# Thymeleaf expression objects: #session and ${session....}

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, session, thymeleaf, httpsession

There are two ways to obtain a session attribute in Thymeleaf:

1. `${#session.getAttribute('attr')}`
2. `${session.attr}`

What is the difference between both `session` "objects"? Is there a situation in which one would work and not the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#session` usage only works in Web Context ie. it is a helper to directly access to the javax.servlet.http.HttpSession object associated with the current request. This is clearly stated in [documentation](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#web-context-objects). So you are directly accessing the Context object here not the variable that is defined by the thymeleaf.

`$session` is a shortcut for accessing session attributes. This is not a context object, but it is a map added to the context as a variable, which is added by thymeleaf explicitly. You can find the relevant information [here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#web-context-namespaces-for-requestsession-attributes-etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Some of the session related object has been removed in new version of the thymeleaf.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).